# How to read each char in a line from a text file to a 2d matrix?

Tags: java, string, matrix, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

I need to create `String[][] resultMatrix = new String[3][4];` to store the values such that each line is a row and each char in a line is an element of that row, but I don't always know the dimensions of the matrix ahead of time.

What I have returns one string, but I need a 3x4 matrix:

```java
public static String[][] readTxt(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

    String line = buffer.readLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    line = null;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    String fileString = sb.toString();
    fileString = fileString
            .replaceAll("\r", "")
            .replaceAll("\n>[A-Z]+", ">")
            .replaceAll("[0-9]+\n", "");

    String[] lines = fileString.split(">");
    String[][] resultMatrix = new String[lines.length][lines[0].length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        resultMatrix[i] = lines[i].split("");
    }

    buffer.close();
    return resultMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made it epically complicated.

EDIT: Turned `collect to list` -> `list to array` into calling `toArray` on stream directly.

```
public static String[][] readTxt(String fn)  throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(fn))
        .map(s -> s.split(""))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

step by step:

> `Files.lines(Paths.get(fn))`

Read the entire `fn` file in, and process it line-by-line

> `.map(s -> s.split(""))`

Turn a String into a String[] by calling `.split("")` - split splits strings on some delimiter, and if you pass the empty string as delimiter, you end up with each and every character separated out. We now have a stream of string arrays

> `.toArray(String[][]::new)`

Turn the stream into an array. This requires telling the `toArray` method how to construct a new array of the right size. `String[][]::new` is java-ese for: The concept of invoking `new String[X][]` given a single int parameter (the size). As in, `String[][]::new` doesn't create a new array. It represents the concept of creating them (It's a method reference: It represents the idea of writing `new String[X][]`).

Comment: Why the intermediate step with the list? You might as well do: `.map(s -> s.split("")).toArray(String[][]::new);`

Comment: Even better - I had a quick look at `Collectors` and was a bit surprised that I didn't find a toArray function there. Bit odd it's built into streams itself. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of strings, then you can convert it to a 2D array of characters as follows:

```java
String[] lines = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"};

String[][] resultMatrix = Arrays.stream(lines)
        .map(str -> str.codePoints()
                .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(resultMatrix));
// [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l]]
```